# Can't scroll VBox full of labels using ScrollPane

Tags: java, javafx, scrollpane, vbox

Basically making a list of labels that add up. As they reach the bottom, they go out of their bounds (Also must be behind the TextField) and is impossible to scroll it.
How to make them behave normally?
Labels are added into VBox that is inside ScrollPane

Picture with problem:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nY8rR.png)

SceneBuilder screenshot:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWxpN.png)

FXML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.canvas.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="root" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.view.GameUIController">
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.6889632107023411" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.8737373737373737" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="398.0" prefWidth="407.0">
                    <items>
                      <AnchorPane minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="160.0">
                           <children>
                              <ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPane" fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" pannable="true" prefWidth="407.0" vvalue="1.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                 <content>
                                    <VBox fx:id="box" minWidth="0.0" />
                                 </content>
                              </ScrollPane>
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
                           <children>
                              <TextField fx:id="textField" onAction="#enterPressed" prefHeight="20.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="-5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" />
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </items>
                  </SplitPane>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" layoutY="44.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="398.0" prefWidth="181.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <items>
                      <AnchorPane fx:id="inventoryPane" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
                           <children>
                              <Label layoutX="48.0" layoutY="30.0" text="Inventory" textAlignment="CENTER" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="5.0">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="22.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                      <AnchorPane fx:id="playerPane" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
                           <children>
                              <Label text="Player" textAlignment="CENTER">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="22.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </items>
                  </SplitPane>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Label adding method is in another thread (Because of game mechanics reasons)

```
@FXML
    public void text(String text1) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Label label = new Label(text1);
                box.getChildren().add(label);

            }
        });
        listener = false;
        // scroll to bottom

    }
```

Comment: Use a `ListView`.

Comment: I went for that option earlier, but it causes too many problems (Couldn't add more items into ListView) so VBox is recommended

Comment: Couldn't add more items into `ListView`? What does that mean? Your `ScrollPane` has a `VBox` with `Label`, but `ListView` does not work. Does not add up.

Comment: Basically I already developed a lot with VBox in mind, so I rather not change it to listView that I do not know how to use

Comment: You need to post a [mcve]. How are those labels added?

Comment: Labels added through a method. They are created with a specific text and added directly into VBox. Tree looks like this: ScrollPane > VBox > Labels

Comment: @Zackyy can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52896649/edit) the post and add the full fxml

Comment: You are basically trying to create a `ListView` that have none of the benefits of a `ListView`. It's probably in your best interest that you learn about `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from the fxml `fitToHeight="true"` and it works good luck man.

Comment: All it changed is the scroll bar size. Problem persists *EDIT: It's also moving up and down now, but the vbox doesnt move along

Comment: Then there is something that you aren't showing us and I cannot help if you dont post the fxml and the relevant code of adding the labels. So I am done helping until that time @me in a comment and ill come help when you do so

Comment: Now it's complete. If you need anything else to know, tell me

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my GameEngine class couldn't see the correct nodes, so I passed them from the controller into the engine methods. Works like a charm now